# What is a gold seal flight instructor?

Tags: faa-regulations, usa, cfi

What is a gold seal flight instructor and how does it differ from a usual flight instructor? Does it offer any additional privileges or prestige?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A gold seal flight instructor is obtained by having a ground instructor certificate and within the previous 24 months have a pass/fail rate of 80% or above and recommending at least 10 applicants.

It is a way for the FAA to recognize the best instructors in the industry.  You do not get any special privileges with the gold seal.

See [AC 61-65](http://www.faa.gov/documentlibrary/media/advisory_circular/ac_61-65e.pdf) for more details.

Comment: No special privileges?  You do get to carry around that fancy gold seal.... http://i.imgur.com/ohFbydJ.png

Comment: You do get listed as such, which gets more students ringing your phone.

Comment: @KeithS speaking from experience, my gold seal did nothing to increase students calling, let alone showing up for flights. :)

Comment: If you are a DPE or a Chief tInstructor at 141 school you can substitute conducitng 20 practical tests in lieu of the 10 candidate/80% pass rate. You can also combine the requirements: (Two practical tests conducted equal the credit given for one applicant trained and recommended for a practical test.)